# Why am I getting an array of SimpleXMLElement Objects here?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, domdocument

I have some code that pulls HTML from an external source:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = @simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');
$sources = array();
```

Then, if I add all of the sources with this code:

```
foreach ($images as $i) {   
  array_push($sources, $i['src']);
}

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($sources);
 die();
```

I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => /images/someimage.gif
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => /images/en/someother.jpg
        )
....
)
```

But when I use this code:

```
foreach ($images as $i) {   
  $sources[] = (string)$i['src'];
}
```

I get this result (which is what is desired):

```
Array
(
    [0] => /images/someimage.gif
    [1] => /images/en/someother.jpg
    ...
)
```

What is causing this difference? 
What is so different about array_push()?

Thanks,

**EDIT:** While I realize the answers match what I am asking (I've awarded), I more wanted to know why whether using array_push or other notation adds the SimpleXMLElement Object and not a string when both **arent** casted. I knew when explicitly casting to a string I'd get a string. See follow up question here:[Why aren't these values being added to my array as strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668561/why-arent-these-values-being-added-to-my-array-as-strings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is not caused by `array_push()` -- but by the **type-cast you are using in the second case**.

In your first loop, you are using :

```
array_push($sources, $i['src']);
```

Which means **you are adding `SimpleXMLElement` objects** to your array.

While, in the second loop, you are using :

```
$sources[] = (string)$i['src'];
```

Which means *(thanks to the cast to string)*, that **you are adding strings** to your array -- and not `SimpleXMLElement` objects anymore.

As a reference : relevant section of the manual : [**Type Casting**][1].

Comment: Thanks - I've posted a follow up question if you'd be so kind. Im more looking to find out when I dont cast that I dont get a string added.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just noticed better answers above, but the regex itself is still valid.
Are you trying to get all images in HTML markup?
I know you are using PHP, but you can convert use this C# example of where to go:

```
List<string> links = new List<string>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlSource))
            {
                string regexImgSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
                MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(htmlSource, regexImgSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
                foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
                {
                    string href = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    links.Add(href);
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you should:

```
array_push($sources, (string) $i['src']);
```

Your second example gives an array of strings because you are converting the SimpleXMLElements to strings using the `(string)` cast. In your first example you are not, so you get an array of SimpleXMLElements instead.