# Why aren't these values being added to my array as strings?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml, domdocument

Further to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667526/why-am-i-getting-an-array-of-simplexmlelement-objects-here), I'm actually wondering why I'm not getting strings added to my array with the following code.

I get some HTML from an external source with this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = @simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple
$images = $xml->xpath('//img');
$sources = array();
```

Here is the images array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [alt] => techcrunch logo
                    [src] => http://s2.wp.com/wp-content/themes/vip/tctechcrunch/images/logos_small/techcrunch2.png?m=1265111136g
                )

        )
   ...
)
```

Then I added the sources to my array with:

```
foreach ($images as $i) {   
  array_push($sources, $i['src']);
}
```

But when I print the results:

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($sources);
 die();
```

I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => http://www.domain.com/someimages.jpg
        )
    ...
)
```

Why isn't  `$i['src']` treated as a string? Isn't the original [src] element noted where I print $images a string inside there?

To put it another way $images[0] is a SimpleXMLElement, I understand that. But **why is the 'src' attribute of THAT object not being but into $sources as a string when I reference it as** `$i['src']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't $i['src'] treated as a string?

Becaue it isn't one - it's a SimpleXMLElement object that gets *cast* to a string if used in a string context, but it still remains a SimpleXMLElement at heart.

To make it a real string, force cast it:

```
array_push($sources, (string) $i['src']);
```

Comment: `array_push($sources, "$i[src]");` should work too, I believe.

Comment: Isn't $images[0] a SimpleXMLElement? Then each object inside of that becomes $i and each attribute of that (e.g [src]) a string??

Comment: @barfoon I don't know the in-depth specifics, but each attribute is *again* a SimpleXMLElement. The properties can be accessed using `foreach` because the class provides a [traversable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). It is *not* an array of strings even though it looks that way when dumping it. This is from experience working with the library - maybe somebody else can explain how this works on a deeper, internal level.

Comment: Thanks Pekka - your last comment made it totally click for me. Even though I saw what looked to be a string when I dumped it, I was actually further getting a SimpleXMLElement - makes sense now.

Comment: a var_dump($i['src']); confirms this. Don't know why I didn't try that before.

Answer (score 1):

Because [**`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) *(quoting)* :

> Returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`
> objects

and not an array of strings.

So, the items of your `$images` array are `SimpleXMLElement` objects, and not strings -- which is why you have to cast them to strings, if you want strings.

Comment: I understand that the method returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. But why is the [src] element of that SimpleXMLElement object not added to my $sources as a string?